# Php page memory limit exceeded

Tags: php

I have a php page that retrieve records from my mongodb. There are a total of 3 select statements on the page in total.
As my sites get bigger, i realized the script is consuming more memory.

When memory exceeded  my page just dies off displaying page cannot be displayed error. My current solution is to increase the limit but i am not sure if that is the right approach.

Default is 128mb. I increased to 256mb to resolve it previously. Now, i faced the same issue.

Is there any way i can do to decrease the memory usage? How do i track the root cause.

advice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the code and data.

Comment: thanks. managed to resolve this issue. It's due to my database select statement not optimized.